# OwnProps not being passed with React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm refactoring an app from V2 to V4 of React Router, and I have run into an issue where properties from my `mapStateToProps` are not being passed down to each component. Here's my setup:

App.jsx

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Navbar />
                <Routes {...this.props} />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const { page } = state
    return {
        routeProps: ownProps,
        page: page
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        pageActions: bindActionCreators(pageActionCreators, dispatch),
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App))
```

Routes.jsx has this line:

`<Route exact path="/:name/information" render={ ({ match }) => <InfoPage {...this.props} match={ match } /> } />`

InfoPage.jsx

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { routeProps, pageActions } = this.props
    pageActions.fetchInfoPage(routeProps.match.params.name)
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.page.page !== nextProps.page.page) {
        const { routeProps, pageActions } = nextProps
        pageActions.fetchInfoPage(routeProps.match.params.name)
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <InfoPageView
        page={ this.props.page }
        pageActions={ this.props.pageActions }
        routeProps={ this.props.routeProps }
        />
    )
}
```

The problem is that when I try to access a route that uses InfoPage, i.e. `/orders/information`, it never loads. When I check Redux dev tools, it says that `page` and `content` are undefined. The only things I changed on the InfoPage component while refactoring were adding in `match.params` instead of `params`. This is leading me to believe that there is something wrong with my Redux/Router integration, specifically with `ownProps/routeProps` not being passed down properly.

Any ideas as to what's wrong here?

Comment: What does the rest of Routes.jsx look like?

Comment: It has a class `Routes` that returns a `<Switch>` with a list of the routes in it. The first two are:

`<Route exact path="/" render={ () => <Home {...this.props} /> } />

<Route exact path="/:name/information" render={ ({location, match}) => <InfoPage {...this.props} { ...location } match={ match } /> } />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure that you're wrapping `Routes.jsx` (as @lemarc and @Kyle Richardson alluded to earlier) so that your routed components will update properly.

When you wrap a connected component with `withRouter`, it will make `match` available in that component's [props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match).

Instead of trying to map `match` via `ownProps`, you can just access it from your wrapped component's `props`.

Also, it looks like you're trying to reference Action Creators which are bound to your `App` component from your child component `InfoPageView`. This is an anti-pattern in React + Redux apps.

If your `InfoPageView` needs the ability to dispatch an Action, you should provide it to `InfoPageView` directly via its own `mapDispatchToProps` function. The same goes for the `page` property you're trying to access; if `InfoPageView` needs to read the value of `page`, you should provide it directly via `mapStateToProps`:

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { connect, bindActionCreators } from 'react-redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import { fetchInfoPage as fetchInfoPageAction } from '../actions/fetchInfoPage'
// ^ import directly from wherever this Action Creator resides in your project ^

class InfoPageView extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {

        const { match } = this.props
        fetchInfoPage(match.params.name) // <-- `match` provided by withRouter()

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        if (this.props.page.page !== nextProps.page.page) {
            const { match, fetchInfoPage } = nextProps
            fetchInfoPage(match.params.name) // <-- `match` provided by withRouter()
        }

    }
    render() {

        return (
            <InfoPageView />
        )

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   page: state.page,
   content: state.content,
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchInfoPage: bindActionCreators(fetchInfoPageAction, dispatch),
})

export default withRouter(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InfoPageView)
)
```

If, after all that, you find that `page` and `content` are still `undefined`, it's likely that they're simply missing from your `page` reducer. Verify that those properties are present in your `page` reducer's `initialState`:

```
const initialState = { page: 1, content: 'initial content' }

const page = (state = initialState, action) => ({
    switch (action.type) {

        // (action type `case` statements here)

        default:
            return state
    }
})

export default page
```

...and also verify that you're passing the `page` reducer to your store via `combineReducers`:

```
import pageReducer from '../reducers/page'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  page: pageReducer,
})

const store = configureStore(
  rootReducer,
  /* store middlewares, etc */
)

export default store
```

Comment: I started dissecting your response piece by piece and figured out the culprit -- it was the way `match` was being mapped. I changed `routeProps.match.params.name` to `match.props.name` after pulling `{ match }` from `this.props` and everything worked. It's a little slow loading but I think that can be fixed once I clean up some more code. One more question - is it generally best practice to use `mapStateToProps` on every individual component rather than just using it on the main overarching `App.jsx` file?

Comment: @wildlifehexagon hey that's good to hear!

yes, it is generally considered best practice to use `mapStateToProps` to retrieve state properties for each component, where you need them. 

A good litmus test is: if you're mapping a value from state onto a parent component like `App` for the *sheer purpose of passing it* to a child component, then you should probably be mapping that value to the child component's props to begin with.

By the way, if you consider you question to be resolved, could you check an Accepted Answer for future visitors?

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try moving your `withRouter` call to Routes.jsx

```
export default withRouter(connect()(Routes))
```

I believe that needs to be in the same file as any `<Route ... />` components.

Comment: This is correct. Your components will not update on route changes if you do not wrap the component that contains your `<Route/>` components with `withRouter`.

Comment: Tried that out, but now I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` error. I'm passing down the `match` object, so not sure what's causing this issue?

Comment: I also tried just adding in my entire `<Switch>` statement with the routes inside App.jsx, but that just brought me back to my initial problem of `page` and `content` being undefined.